# C string(char array): ignores next scanf because of spaces

Tags: c, string

say something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

  char fname[30];
  char lname[30];

  printf("Type first name:\n");
  scanf("%s", fname);

  printf("Type last name:\n");
  scanf("%s", lname);

  printf("Your name is: %s %s\n", fname, lname);
}
```

if i type `"asdas asdasdasd"` for `fname`, it won't ask me to input something for `lname` anymore. I just want to ask how i could fix this, thank you.

Comment: scanf function reads one word not a line with spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`fgets`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Line-Input.html#index-fgets-996) (or `getline` if you are using GNU) to get an entire line instead of until the first whitespace.

```
if (fgets(fname, 30, stdin) == NULL) {
    // TODO: Read failed: handle this.
}
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/ttz6Q)

You could also consider using the function `fgets_wrapper` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4309845/61974) as it will also remove the new line character for you.

Comment: @user974227: It *will* work, you just did something else wrong. Please show what you tried.

Comment: something like this
 printf("Level %d\nName: ",i);
        fgets ( tempName, 32, stdin );
        printf("\nDescription: ");
        fgets ( tempDesc, 128, stdin );

Answer (score 5):

Putting `%s` in a format list makes `scanf()` to read characters until a *whitespace* is found. Your input string contains a space so the first `scanf()` reads `asdas` only. Also `scanf()` is considered to be dangerous (think what will happen if you input more then 30 characters), that is why as indicated by others you should use `fgets()`.

Here is how you could do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char fname[30];
    char lname[30];

    printf("Type first name:\n");
    fgets(fname, 30, stdin);

    /* we should trim newline if there is one */
    if (fname[strlen(fname) - 1] == '\n') {
        fname[strlen(fname) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    printf("Type last name:\n");
    fgets(lname, 20, stdin);
    /* again: we should trim newline if there is one */
    if (lname[strlen(lname) - 1] == '\n') {
        lname[strlen(lname) - 1] = '\0';
    }

    printf("Your name is: %s %s\n", fname, lname);

    return 0;
}
```

However this piece of code is still not complete. You still should check if `fgets()` has encountered some errors. Read more on `fgets()` [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fgets.html).

Comment: i saw this one too!:) and i tried it in my code, what happened was, my first scanf was ignored

Comment: @user974227 Why do you need *scanf()* any more? Use `fgets()` only.

Comment: i meant, first input was ignored. i changed all the scanf to fgets

Answer (score 2):

change

```
scanf("%s", fname);
```

to

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", fname);
```

[^\n] is accept other than '\ n'

%*c is ignore one character('\n')

Comment: Does this belong to standard?

Comment: try for easy test: gcc -std=c99 sample.c or gcc -std=c89 sample.c

Comment: I think fgets better than scanf, too.